# Run flutter project which is located in another disk

Tags: permissions, hard-drive, ssd, disk-usage, 21.04

I have two disks on my computer:

- 128 GB SSD
- 1 TB HDD

I have installed Ubuntu into **SSD**. As my **SSD's** volume is small, I have to place my flutter projects in **HDD**. But when I try to run my project which is in **HDD** I have this issue:

```
FileSystemException: Cannot create link, path =
'/media/USER_NAME/B318-224E/Dev/FlutterProjects/autotest/linux/
flutter/ephemeral/.plugin_symlinks/path_provider_linux' (OS Error: Operation not
permitted, errno = 1)
```

How can I give permission to run my projects which are in my HDD?

Comment: Explore your permission/ownership problems with `https://github.com/waltinator/pathlld`. A `bash` script to answer "Why can't I Read/Write that file?".

Comment: Can you explain a little more.

Comment: I do explain more in `pathlld`s `README` file. What, precisely, needs "more explanation"?